# How do I add a button in a table view cell that plays a different sound file on each row with swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, button, audio

I wanted to be able to put a button in the `UITableViewCell` where I can click the button and it plays a different sound file on each row. what is the best code to put in to make that happen?

Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!
var arrayOfPersons: [Person] = [Person]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.setUpPersons()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setUpPersons()
{
    let person1 = Person(name: "Anna\nAnna2\nAnna3", number: 60, imageName: "testingimage.jpg", soundButton: "dimsumgirl.mp3")
    let person2 = Person(name: "Joes", number: 10, imageName: "testingimage2.jpg", soundButton: "dimsumgirl.mp3")

    arrayOfPersons.append(person1)
    arrayOfPersons.append(person2)

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
 {
    return arrayOfPersons.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! CustomCell



    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }

    let person = arrayOfPersons [indexPath.row]

    cell.setCell(person.name, rightlabelInt: person.number, imageName: person.imageName, soundButton: person.soundButton)



    return cell
```

I have tried using the code above but I can't seem to quite figure out how to make the picture a button instead and be able to play sound with each button.

Really appreciate some help!

Thank you!

Comment: whats wrong with your code ? what do you mean picture a button ?

Comment: Hi Mr.T, I wanted to change the code so instead of having a picture in the row I want to have a button which plays a different sound file on each row.

Answer (score 1):

In your custom cell you should have a button and hook up the touch event inside that cell as well. Inside setCell make the background image of the button the image you pass and set a class variable to the sound file you passed in. Then when the IBAction touch event is fired play the sound from the class variable.

Comment: Hi Jeremiah, thanks for the information. I am bit new at this, how would I set a class variable and be able to add different sound files for different buttons on different rows?

Comment: You are setting a class variable inside CustomCell. That variable will be different in every row. So for instance inside setCell: self.soundButton = soundButton. Then inside the button click you play(self.soundButton), whatever that entails.